# Is there a way to run Android emulator and VmWare Player at the same time on windows 10?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, virtual-machine

Im using Xamarin in VS2015 on windows 10 to build a cross platform app.
And im using VmWare's VMPlayer to run a virtual instance of OS X to run the iOS emulator. VmPlayer doesn't work with Hyper-V turned ON and the Android Emulator doesnt work with Hyper-V turned OFF.

I was wondering if there is a work around that will allow both the VMplayer and the Android emulator to run at the same time without having to go back and forth turning Hyper-V on and off?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the Visual Studio Android Emulator in vmWare (if you virtualize Windows):

- The VM must have at least 2 CPUs assigned
- Change the OS type of the VM to "Hyper-V (unsupported)” in the VM's general setting
- This step was not required for me in vmWare 8: In Windows, edit the `c:\program files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10240.0\skus\android\xdesku.xml` file and remove the following line from the file: `GuestDisplayProvider=”VsEmulator.OpenGLGuestDisplay`

If your Windows machine is a physical machine, you can run the VS Android Emulator directly there.

Comment: I figure that a few years might be enough time to wait... Have you had a chance to try and see if it works?